# No parallax plugins are working for my website

Tags: jquery, html, stellar.js

I'm trying to use the Stellar Jquery plugin to have a parallax scrolling on a background image, but it does not appear to be working, I've tried many different variables

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.stellar.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

I put my script tags after the body

```
<section class="hashtag" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
```

This is the section I'm trying to apply the scrolling

I've done everything -> `background-attachment:fixed;` , `$.stellar();`
I cant find the issue
, doc for reference -> [Doc](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/docs/)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Have you checked the browser's console for errors?

Comment: @j08691 
Uncaught TypeError: e.indexOf is not a function
    at w.fn.init.w.fn.load (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at e.refresh (jquery.stellar.min.js:2)
    at e.init (jquery.stellar.min.js:2)
    at new e (jquery.stellar.min.js:2)
    at HTMLElement.<anonymous> (jquery.stellar.min.js:2)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.each (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.a.fn.(anonymous function) [as stellar] (file:///Users/DanV/Documents/brandUpdate/js/jquery.stellar.min.js:2:11959)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (script.js:11)
    at l (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)